# Dbinom function shows nonsense calculation

Tags: r

I am trying to get iteration of Binomial Distribution of 12 size with probability 0.29

I tried this code:

```
dbinom(0:12, 12, 0.29)
```

but returned output like this :

```
dbinom(0:12, 12, 0.29)  
[1] 1.640968e-02 8.043056e-02 1.806855e-01 2.460038e-01 2.260810e-01 1.477487e-01  
[7] 7.040606e-02 2.464920e-02 6.292491e-03 1.142299e-03 1.399718e-04 1.039483e-05  
[13] 3.538148e-07
```

This is nonsense since probability shouldn't be bigger than 1.

Could anyone explain is something wrong with my input? Or maybe it's a bug instead ?

Comment: None of these numbers are larger than 1. In fact, they sum to 1, as expected. Try `sum(dbinom(0:12, 12, 0.29))`  and you will confirm that. The numbers in the output are simply in scientific notation, where the number after the `e` means the number to which 10 should be raised to give the actual value. The first number is therefore 0.01640968 (i.e. 1.640968 * 10^-2)

Answer (score 0):

Which value is larger than 1???

Try adding this before your code

```
options(scipen=999)
```

Comment: x=11 and x=12 , but when i calculated in a paper using binomial distribution formula it's resulting the same, i think there's nothing wrong with the R and i should've asked math stack exchange instead cuz the topic i should ask is about probability instead